# Undefined index while checking for COOKIE in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I set a cookie on a visitor's PC to show a notice once every 24 hours. Recently I started getting the following error in my error log:

```
PHP: undefined index notice in **
```

I use the following code to check if the cookie exists with value and if not show notice:

```
if($_COOKIE['notice'] != 'yes')  
   echo 'notice';
}
```

I can use the following to avoid the PHP notice:

```
if((isset($_COOKIE['notice']) || !isset($_COOKIE['notice'])) && $_COOKIE['notice'] != 'yes')
```

Is there a way to do this check in one step only like I was doing or in a similar way?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The index 'notice' in your source does not match the reported index 'test' in the error message. To avoid notices, you validate a variable or an index before reading it.

Here are two functions for the validation.

### isset()

Is a positive check that the variable/index is set and not NULL

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['notice']) && $_COOKIE['notice'] === 'yes') {
  // success
  echo 'Cookie equals "yes".';
}
```

You can use && (and) for a second condition, that has to be TRUE, too.

### empty()

Is a negative check that the index/variable does not exists or has a value that is considered empty (NULL, 0, '', array()).

```
if (empty($_COOKIE['notice']) || $_COOKIE['notice'] !== 'yes') {
   // error
  echo 'Cookie does not exists, is empty or does not equal "yes".';
}
```

You can use || (or) to combine that with additional conditions that need to be FALSE, too.

Or use the operator:

### ??

The operator assign a default value if the variable/index is not set or NULL:

```
$noticeCookie = (string)($_COOKIE['notice'] ?? 'no');
if ($noticeCookie === 'yes') {
  // success
  echo 'Cookie equals "yes".';

}
```

Comment: the notice is actually due to this variable..i just wrote it wrong in the question. Your answer won't work because what about if the cookie is set but doesn't have the value 'yes'?

Comment: I made the examples a little more specific.

Comment: again...the first function is positive so it's irrelevant...it checks if the cookie has value 'yes'...regarding the second one, what about if the cookie EXITS, has value, but the value is not equal 'yes'

Comment: ohh...sorry...i assume empty is the same as !isset except !isset for null values only....so you are right :)

Answer (score 1):

You always need to know if a variable is set before try to find what is inside, so yes.. you need to do the check. Also, your logic is wrong.. you are checking if `notice` is or isn't set (allways true) and checking if `notice` is "yes".

The code should be something like this:

```
if ( (!isset($_COOKIE['notice'])) || ( (isset($_COOKIE['notice'])) && ($_COOKIE['notice'] != 'yes') ) ) {
  //Show the notice
}
```

Comment: it won't work like this because your code is checking whether the cookie isset...what about if it's not set, the notice won't be displayed...I was checking for `$_COOKIE['notice'] != 'yes'` before getting this notice which was making sure if the cookie was set or not and if it has the value 'yes'

Comment: this is actually my answer if you look for my second bit of code :D I want to know if there is a shorter way to do it or not?

Comment: Is not the same, check it. Also no, without a custom function isn't possible to make it short.

Comment: here is my code `if((isset($_COOKIE['notice']) || !isset($_COOKIE['notice'])) && $_COOKIE['notice'] != 'yes')
` isn't this the same except I mention the `ISSET` before the `!ISSET`?

Comment: In English words (or something like, my primary language isn't english): You are evaluating the following. If the cookie `notice` exist, then show the notice (`||` is a short circuit OR) or if `notice` is not set and the cookie is not set then show the notice. Which is wrong, because if if you don't have the cookie, you don't and have the value. Also you will get a NOTICE because of that.

Comment: got you...your logic is more correct although both are giving me the same result

Comment: but what about this `!isset($_COOKIE['notice']) || $_COOKIE['notice'] != 'yes'`...this will check if cookie not existing OR if it is not equal to 'yes' (which means it exists but not equal to 'yes')